# A process is a program that is loaded into RAM

Tags: process

Is this correct? Basically, programs are simply code on hard disk and they are called process(es) when they are in the RAM, right?

Comment: A complete explanation can be found in [The Design of the UNIX Operating System](http://www.tenox.net/docs/the_design_of_the_unix_operating_system.pdf) (Maurice J. Bach, 1986), chapter 2, section 2.2.2 (Introduction to system concepts, processes) and chapter 6 (The structure of processes).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theatrical operating systems in general

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this might be a little clumsy, you could say that. Creating a process takes two steps:

1. Allocate a *u area* (basically, information about the process that is accessible to the kernel), fill an entry in the process table, initialise all related components... basically, just create another process for the kernel to manage. This is done through the `fork` system call.
2. Load an executable file into memory. This is done through the `exec` (now `execve`) system call. During this call, 3 main memory areas, called *regions* are filled:

   - The *text* region, which consists of a set of instructions your process is to follow : basically, your program. This is contained within your executable file (the compiler writes it based on your source code).
   - The *data* region, which contains your initialised data (variables with values, e.g. `int myvar = 1`) and enough space to hold unitialised data (called *bss*), such as an array (e.g. `char buffer[256]`).
   - The *stack* region. This part is a little trickier to explain, and as I said in a comment, [Maurice J. Bach does it better than I ever would](http://www.tenox.net/docs/the_design_of_the_unix_operating_system.pdf) (chapter 2, section 2.2.2). Basically, the stack is a dynamic area in memory, which grows as functions are called, and shrinks as they return. When executing a program, frames corresponding to the `main` function are pushed onto the stack. These frames will be popped when the program terminates.

Now, while this might seem enough to run a program, it isn't. Now that your process is running, the kernel still needs to maintain it. Quoting:

> As outlined in Chapter 2, the lifetime of a process can be conceptually divided into a set of states that describe the process. *(The Design of the UNIX Operating System, Maurice J. Bach, chapter 6 : the structure of processes)*.

This means that your process will not always be "running", nor will it always be in primary storage (what you call "RAM"). For instance:

- If your process ever goes to sleep (because it is told to by its *text*, or because it is waiting for something), the kernel may decide to swap it out to secondary storage (usually a swap area). When this happens, your process is no longer in primary storage ("in memory/RAM") : the kernel has saved it, and will be able to reschedule it once it's been loaded back into primary storage.
- If your process ran enough time, and the kernel decides to *preempt* it (and let another process run instead for some time), it may swap it out again if it cannot hold it into memory.

A typical life for a process is...

1. Created: the `fork` system call has been used.
2. Ready to run (in memory) : instructions and data have been loaded.
3. Running (switching between user and kernel mode, probably several times..)
4. Sleeping, waking up, sleeping, waking up, ...
5. Exiting (final switch to kernel mode, zombie state, disappearance).

*Steps 3 and 4 may actually interweave.*

Note that *processes* are one of two main concepts on UNIX systems (along with *files*). For this reason, it is impossible to cover everything about them in a Q&A format. The book I kept quoting in my answer is an excellent reference for UNIX systems, and while *NIXes/UNIX-like system may differ in some areas, they still rely on the same concepts.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the Wikipedia page: "*a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) is an instance of a computer program that is being executed*".

So if usually to be executed the program needs to be loaded in RAM, a process is not necessarily in RAM.

You can for example thing about a sleeping process being put in swap. The process is still running (i.e. it is being listed using the [ps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps_%28Unix%29) command) but its state has been written on disk to free some RAM space.

Comment: What if the statement is like this, "A process is a program that has been loaded into RAM but not necessarily to be currently in RAM"?

Comment: @RonVince Loading the executable file into RAM is just one step... Creating and maintaining a process takes more effort than that.

Comment: @RonVince, ...a running program has certainly been mapped into *virtual* memory, but that doesn't mean its entire text has necessarily been loaded into *physical* memory even once.